# How to apply overlay only on the item when select listview item

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm having trouble highlighting selected item in ListView. Basically, I wanted to highlight selected item by applying an overlay **ONLY** on top of the item.

I have two 9-patch images which I originally used for normal/pressed state on list item background. However, the effect only apply to the background and not other view creating strage looking effect for us. We want to be able to highlight the view when selected.

I now set drawSelectorOnTop to true. I also use the pressed state background in listSelector as well. This create similar effect. However, the highlight item are now bigger than the rest although the image I use was perfectly fine as a background.

Basically, what we wanted to achieve is the same selector effect as seen on Google Play store, Google Play Music, Google Keep. My list item feature ImageView quite heavily and I want the selector to highlight over that but not the background.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:[ListView - Highlight sub layout of item.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602021/listview-highlight-sub-layout-of-item/19624120#19624120) I've implemented exactly what I think you're looking to do.